# Does it make sense to have a question-is-an-example-of feature?

Tags: feature-request

It's clear that some questions are broader than others.

Does it make sense to be able to tag a question as not a duplicate of another question, but perhaps a more specific instance of a broader question?

I feel like if the broader question has a more general answer, this would be teaching people to fish instead of answering their specific question.

Comment: That is usually covered by just closing as a duplicate of the broader one. I guess you could leave a comment saying its a more specific case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a question who's answer answers another question effectively, you can close it as a duplicate.  Even if there are differences between the questions, as long as the answer solves that problem (either because the differences aren't relevant to the answer, or because the linked duplicate is covering a more general case), the closure is appropriate.

There's no need for a different kind of closure to cover these situations; "duplicate" covers it just fine as it is.